# Openpyxl: value error: Color must be aRGB hex values

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

When I try to read the file using `openpyxl.load_workbook`, I get the following error -
`Openpyxl: value error: Color must be aRGB hex values`.

The Excel file that I am trying to read has some cells with teal color. When I manually open the excel file and change the cell color to white, it works and reads the file. But with some colors like teal, it does not work and throws the error.

Appreciate it, if someone could help me with this. Thank you!